# LINQ: How to remove element from IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

How do you loop through IQueryable and remove some elements I don't need.

I am looking for something like this

```
var items = MyDataContext.Items.Where(x => x.Container.ID == myContainerId);
foreach(Item item in items)
{
  if(IsNotWhatINeed(item))
    items.Remove(item); 
}
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to query that further as in this

```
var filtered = items.Where(itm => IsWhatINeed(itm));
```

Also notice the subtle change in the boolean function to an affirmative rather than a negative. That (the negative) is what the `not` operator is for.

Comment: With such an optimistic and positive function, you can also write `items.Where(IsWhatINeed)`.

Comment: The positive version of a function also eliminates the double negative scenario: `!IsNotWhatINeed()`

Answer (score 10):

```
items = items.Where( x => !IsNotWhatINeed(x) );
```

Comment: I'd like to add that in LINQ, as with all functional code, it's more preferable to get a new list from old ones by applying a filter instead of making changes to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
var items = MyDataContext.Items.Where(x => x.Container.ID == myContainerId 
    && !IsNotWhatINeed(x));
```

or

```
var items = MyDataContext.Items.Where(x => x.Container.ID == myContainerId) 
    .Where(x=> !IsNotWhatINeed(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct in that you can further refine the query with a 'where' statement. However, I'm assuming your query is a Linq2Sql query. So you need to make sure you have the data in memory before further filtering with a custom function:

```
var items = MyDataContext.Items.Where(x => x.Container.ID == myContainerId)
    .ToList(); // fetch the data in memory

var itemsToRemove = items.Where(IsNotWhatINeed);
```

If you really want to extend the IQueryable, then the 'IsNotWhatINeed' function must be translated to something that Linq2Sql understands.

Comment: Thanks jeroenh, could you explain or give me an example what Linq2Sql query is and what Linq2sql understands please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var items = YourDataContext.Items.Where(x => x.Container.ID == myContainerId 
    && !IsNotWhatYouNeed(x));
```