# Remove all items from a list that do not contain a unique word from an array

Tags: c#, razor, logic

I have a `string[]` of unique words and an `IQueryable<>` of a unique class, which contains a string. I'd like to remove all items from the `IQueryable<>` whose string variable does not contain one of the unique words. How can I do this in a way that will not be a serious drain on my code at runtime?

One of the variables is `string Name`. I have an `IQueryable<Project>` and a `string[] words`. I'd like to create a *new* `IQueryable<Project>` where all of the Project's Name contains at least one of the words in the words array.

I don't know how exactly how to do this without looping through the `IQueryable` twice (once to mark the `Projects` that have a `Name` containing a word in the array, and again to move those `Projects` into a new `IQueryable`) which for a large `IQueryable` would be a serious time strain.

Comment: You should post the code you're trying and the errors it would throw.

Comment: @dcg I don't even know what to try because I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you be more precise. I'm a bit confused with your description. Does your IQueryble<> is a IQueryable<string>? On which item should elements be removed etc.

Comment: @LionelD see my edit

Comment: this page tells you how to remove from IQueryable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937528/linq-how-to-remove-element-from-iqueryablet

Comment: You are a bit unclear about Removing vs Filtering the list. Remove means Delete-in-Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the Name property is just a string with multiple words:

```
var newQueryable = queryable
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Where(project => words
                .Intersect(project.Name.Split(' '), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .Any())
       .AsQueryable();
```

dont use the split function if the Name is already an array which consits of all the words.

Comment: It's a start but Project.Name has multiple Words

Comment: I tried this exactly and my code threw the exception `{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\`1[System.String] Intersect[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\`1[System.String], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\`1[System.String], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer\`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}`

Comment: @jαsοndιnAlt This works great. Do you know what I could add to make it ignore punctuation in the project.Name string?

Comment: you will have to implement a custom IgnorePunctuationEqualityComparer  and replace "StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase" with it.

Comment: You can accomplish the ignoring by tweaking `string.Split()`.